# Visual Studio Code: Open _Init_.py instead of function.json by default

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, ide

I am developing Azure Functions. Azure Functions are located in my workspace. When I click an Azure Function then function.json opens. After that I have to select the Python file to edit the Azure Function.

How to let Visual Studio Code open the Python file inmediatly after clicking the Azure Function in my workspace.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> When I click an Azure Function then function.json opens

This is because the function.json file is the main configuration file for the function, so when you click the Azure Function in your workspace, it automatically opens function.json file.

The function.json file consists of information about the triggers, bindings, and other settings for the function. It is used to define the behavior of the function and how it interacts with other Azure services.

To select and edit `_init_.py`, Click on Explorer in the left pane and select `_init.py_` file as shown below:

[image]